# Why isn't Zend mail being sent on my AWS server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, zend-framework

Mail is not working on my AWS server with zend.

I have used:

[GitHub link](https://github.com/christophervalles/Amazon-SES-Zend-Mail-Transport) this library for mail

I have set **AMAZON_AWS_ACCESS_KEY** and **AMAZON_AWS_PRIVATE_KEY** but its not working

Please give me any idea for this problem

this is my action

```
public function testmailAction() {
    
        echo 'Access '.AMAZON_AWS_ACCESS_KEY . "<br/>";
        echo 'Private '.AMAZON_AWS_PRIVATE_KEY. "<br/>";
        echo 'From '.AMAZON_SES_FROM_ADDRESS. "<br/>";
        echo 'To '.AMAZON_SES_TO_ADDRESS. "<br/>";
        
        
        //Load the required dependencies
        require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
        require_once 'App/Mail/Transport/AmazonSES.php';
        
        $mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
        $transport = new App_Mail_Transport_AmazonSES(
            array(
                'accessKey' => AMAZON_AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                'privateKey' => AMAZON_AWS_PRIVATE_KEY
            )
        );
        
        $mail->setBodyText('Lorem Ipsum Dolo Sit Amet');
        $mail->setBodyHtml('Lorem Ipsum Dolo <b>Sit Amet</b>');
        $mail->setFrom(AMAZON_SES_FROM_ADDRESS, 'John Doe');
        $mail->addTo(AMAZON_SES_TO_ADDRESS);
        $mail->setSubject('Test email from Amazon SES without attachments');
        $mail->send($transport);
    die('success');
    }
```

I have used AmazonSES.php class for email setting when I am runing this action then its print 'success' but I am not getting any mail in my mail inbox and error in code.

Comment: Need more information, how is it "not working"?

Comment: @Tomdarkness added some more information

Comment: @Tomdarkness check this now

Comment: Interesting... I had similar issue... anyways, what is `AMAZON_SES_TO_ADDRESS` set to? your email address?

Comment: @KarmicDice yes AMAZON_SES_TO_ADDRESS is mine address and From address is confirmed address

Comment: Do you have production access to amazon SES? If not, the AMAZON_SES_TO_ADDRESS also needs to be a confirmed address.

Comment: @Tomdarkness Yes I have, but when I test mail through amazon test mail(verify email address tab) its working fine . But when I used above code then its not working

Comment: did you uncomment mail configuration in php.ini of amazon server? or did you tried with simple mail function of php?

Comment: @Harish Yes I tried simple mail function on amazon server that not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559063/simple-php-mail-function-not-working-on-amazon-server-ec2

Comment: Best option is to first establish whether it is SES configuration problem or your application problem.

You can try this code to check whether it works with simple PHP?
[Sending Email Through Amazon SES From Your Application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-app.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu-Linux or similar, have you got postfix or any other mail delivery application installed?

If you have got a mail service installed, try checking the mail log.   Please tell me what service you have installed and I might have an idea on where the logs are stored.