# Simple PHP Mail function not working on Amazon server EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I have a PHP script that is supposed to send an email. The script works fine on my local machine, but when I run it on an Amazon Linux server, it doesn't send the email.

```
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
```

Comment: Do you have also the [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)?

Comment: Then you could check these links (using PHPMailer) [Link 1](http://www.kileev.com/2013/02/how-to-send-email-with-phpmailer-using.html) & [Link 2](http://www.johnboy.com/blog/sending-email-with-amazon-ses-smtp-and-phpmailer)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd had the same issue as you in sending an email using Php's `mail()`. Installing send mail solved it for me.

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue with ec2 for php mail.

Solution worked for me:

1. install sendmail by command:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install sendmail
   ```
2. check the service whether its started or not by execuring follwing command

   ```
   service sendmail status
   ```

   Note: Output of above command should be something - `'Active: active (running)'`
3. start the service if it is not running by following command

   ```
   service sendmail start
   ```
4. After the service is started, send a test mail using following command:

   ```
   echo "This is test mail body" | mail -s "Test Mail Subject" "recipient@email.com"
   ```

Replace email with your email ID and see if you receive this email, if yes, then your mail setup is fine and now your php email should be working fine.

If not, file to check for errors is /var/spool/mail/.

Comment: The program 'mail' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:

Comment: @SaravananNandhan you can go through this solution. you need to install mail

Comment: Not working through it.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon server allow sendmail functionality using localhost. Please uncomment mail configuration in php.ini.

I have already done this and working fine.

Comment: which setting would that be?

Comment: when I am using amazon for mail then that is not working in localhost, Please provide me example for amazon mail for localhost

Answer (score 1):

are you willing to use other mailing framework? If yes, you can use phpmailer...it works fine for me.

here is the link on their site. http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: its not working on server

Answer (score 1):

Apparently sending PHP from EC2 is not possible until it gets unlocked by support. To unlock it visit:
[EC2 - Fresh PHP install - Mail not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292170/ec2-fresh-php-install-mail-not-working)

Otherwise, i will just quote @Charles answer:

> This won't directly solve your issue (edit: I mean the error message
>   you have now edited out), but Amazon EC2 instances have a really
>   spotty mail reputation. You're probably going to have deliverability
>   issues.
>
> Thankfully Amazon created the Simple Email Service to go along with
>   EC2, with a free level of service for EC2 customers. The API is pretty
>   simple and there are transport adapters for many excellent PHP mailing
>   libraries, like SwiftMailer (transport).

So - no you can't send, but use [Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/), libraries like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), or I would add services like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/)

*Source: [Another SO question on php mail & EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292170/ec2-fresh-php-install-mail-not-working)

MEANWHILE:
I signed up for Simple Email Service, which is somewhat what SendGrid is doing. It's was very simple. First you request smtp user and password. You then either confirm an email for testing, or request production access [I didn't need that so I haven't gone through process]. And one caveat - use `ssl://` in front of the host, or it will give you `SMTP error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.` error. I was using CakePHP and EC2 when this happened.

Answer (score -2):

Just follow instructions below (Tested for ubuntu 10x EC2)

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear   // Install php-pear if not installed 

sudo pear install mail  

sudo pear install Net_SMTP

sudo pear install Auth_SASL

sudo pear install mail_mime

sudo apt-get install postfix

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Enjoy!