# Amazon EC2 instance mail is not working in bitnami server

Tags: php, email, amazon-ec2

I have install mail sent in php script but mail are not received any mail.

- sudo apt-get install sendmail
- Also restart & reboot the EC2 server .

This code is working in another server don not working in Amzon ec2 how it works in Amazon ec2

```
<?php
/*
 * Enable error reporting
 */
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );

/*
 * Setup email addresses and change it to your own
 */
$from = "dhokaijaydeep@yahoo.com";
$to = "dhokaijaydeep@gmail.com";
$subject = "Simple test for mail function";
$message = "This is a test to check if php mail function sends out the email";
$headers = "From:" . $from;

 // $headers = 'From:'.$from.'<' . $from . '>' . "\r\n"; message: 
// $message = "This is a test to check if php mail function sends out the email. \n\r";


/*
 * Test php mail function to see if it returns "true" or "false"
 * Remember that if mail returns true does not guarantee
 * that you will also receive the email
 */
if(mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers))
{
    echo "Test email send.";
} 
else 
{
    echo "Failed to send.";
}
?>
```

Comment: after installing sendmail, have you restarted your server?

Comment: check your `php.ini`, sendmail is enable or not

Comment: Also restart & reboot the EC2 server .

Comment: How to check mail function enable in php.ini

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196421/php-mail-function-is-not-working-in-aws-ec2

Comment: try setting header and message as this: `$headers = 'From:'.$from.'<' . $from . '>' . "\r\n";` message: `$message = "This is a test to check if php mail function sends out the email. \r\n";`

Comment: it's not working.

Comment: try `var_dump(mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers));` and see if it is returning `true` or not